# How can I correctly use NpgsqlTransaction inside a IAsyncEnumerable emitter function?

Tags: c#, postgresql, transactions, ado.net, iasyncenumerable

I don't need to catch the exception, but I do need to Rollback if there is an exception:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<Item> Select()
{
    var t = await con.BeginTransactionAsync(token);
    try {
        var batchOfItems = new List<Item>(); //Buffer, so the one connection can be used while enumerating items
        using (var reader = await com.ExecuteReaderAsync(SQL, token)) 
        {
            while (await reader.ReadAsync(token))
            {
                var M = await Materializer(reader, token);
                batchOfItems.Add(M);
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in batchOfItems)
        {
            yield return item;
        }

        await t.CommitAsync();
    }
    catch
    {
        await t.RollbackAsync();
    }
    finally
    {
        await t.DisposeAsync();
    }
}
```

(This code is a simplified version of what I am doing, for illustration purposes)

This fails with the message:

> cannot yield a value in the body of a try block with a catch clause

---

This is similar to [Yield return from a try/catch block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245150/yield-return-from-a-try-catch-block), but this has novel context:

- "IAsyncEnumerable" which is relatively new.
- Postgresql (for which the answer uses an internal property)
- This question has a better title, explicitly referring to "Transaction" context. Other contexts with the same error message won't have the same answer.

This is not the same as [Why can't yield return appear inside a try block with a catch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346365/why-cant-yield-return-appear-inside-a-try-block-with-a-catch). In my case, the context is more specific: I need the catch block to Rollback, not to do anything else. Also, as you can see, I already know the answer and created this as a Q&A combo. As you can see from the answer, that answer isn't relevant to [Why can't yield return appear inside a try block with a catch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346365/why-cant-yield-return-appear-inside-a-try-block-with-a-catch)

Comment: This is not the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346365/why-cant-yield-return-appear-inside-a-try-block-with-a-catch. In my case, the context is more specific - I need the catch block to Rollback, not to do anything else.

Comment: What's the point of using `IAsyncEnumerable` here? As far as I can see, it's only making your code more complex than it should be

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto "(This code is a simplified version of what I am doing, for illustration purposes)" thanks

Comment: The first thing is that you didn't answer my question, and a simplification of code shouldn't change its meaning. The second thing is that just because you want a specific behavior on `catch`, it doesn't at all mean that the duplicate doesn't apply here

Comment: My question was just closed as duplicate with no listing of which moderators I need to contact. If you look at my comment I already stated how this is different to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346365/why-cant-yield-return-appear-inside-a-try-block-with-a-catch. Despite that, this it was closed without justifying why here in the comments. That's just inconsiderate and unkind.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346365/why-cant-yield-return-appear-inside-a-try-block-with-a-catch) is about *why*. This question is about *how*. It is a relevant but different question.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I hope I can convince you I'm a genuine hard working person who checks other similar questions thoroughly. It would seem you have jumped the gun in closing my question. I created this as a self-learning Q&A combo - answering my own question for the benefit of others. Mine is quite different, please have a look at my answer; which would not work on that other similar question, where the exception object is to be used for something `Console.WriteLine(e.Message);`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias The answer posted here is based on the answer that Jon Skeet gave on the duplicate. In simple terms: *you can't do this, find an alternative*. In the simplest example (and to demonstrate this Q&A isn't needed): it's enough to have a `bool` variable set to `true` at the end of the `try` block and check its value in the `finally` block

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The use of a boolean latch won't work on the other question. I would have answered there if that worked. Having a boolean latch doesn't capture the exception for error logging (Console.WriteLine).

Comment: You're right, it's not *100% identical*. I've edited the duplicate target, took me 2 seconds to find it :) As a note, this is the query I used: `site:stackoverflow.com yield in try catch`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Good find, the question title you link to is too broad and it's marked  as a duplicate. Where it leads is every broader. It's a bit of a mess. This duplicate marking isn't helping.

Comment: The duplicate target in the linked question is *terrible* IMO. I could agree to reopen that question. As for the question issues, I'd strongly suggest you to edit it into better shape

Comment: Another suggestion I would find better, is to post a new Q&A that is more generic and use that as a canonical reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the Rollback to the finally block if you can check whether or not the transaction was committed, which you can do using `IsCompleted`

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<Item> Select()
{
    var t = await con.BeginTransactionAsync(token);
    try {
        var batchOfItems = new List<Item>(); //Buffer, so the one connection can be used while enumerating items
        async using (var reader = await com.ExecuteReaderAsync(SQL, token)) 
        {
            while (await reader.ReadAsync(token))
            {
                var M = await Materializer(reader, token);
                batchOfItems.Add(M);
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in batchOfItems)
        {
            yield return item;
        }

        await t.CommitAsync();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (t.IsCompleted == false) //Implemented on NpgsqlTransaction, but not DbTransaction
            await t.RollbackAsync();
        await t.DisposeAsync();
    }
}
```

Note: The catch block has been removed, and the finally block has two lines added to the start.

This same approach can also work on other `DbTransaction` implementations that don't have `IsCompleted`

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7245193/887092

Comment: Are you sure that the [`SqlTransaction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction) class has an `IsCompleted` property?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I'm using postgres NpgsqlTransaction. I'll add that to the question tags. Good pickup - thanks.

Comment: As a side note, you could use the [`await using`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58791938/c-sharp-8-understanding-await-using-syntax) syntax, so that you don't have to deal with explicitly disposing the `IAsyncDisposable` object.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thanks, done. I'm not used to IAsyncEnumerable and IAsyncDisposable yet, this is the first time I'm using them.

Comment: An interesting excerpt from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbtransaction.dispose#remarks): *Dispose should rollback the transaction. However, the behavior of Dispose is provider specific, and should not replace calling Rollback.*

Comment: Yeah, I did look up the implementation for Pg, and it did not seem to rollback. Ideally, the .Net team would find a way to catch over a yield.

Answer (score 1):

DbTransaction is considered the best way to manage transactions on SqlConnections, but TransactionScope is also valid, and might help others in related scenarios

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<Item> Select()
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        con.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current); //it's better to open the connection here, then dispose, but this will work
        com = con.CreateCommand(); //Probably need a new command object so it has the transaction context
        var batchOfItems = new List<Item>(); //Buffer, so the one connection can be used while enumerating items
        
        async using (var reader = await com.ExecuteReaderAsync(SQL, token)) 
        {
            while (await reader.ReadAsync(token))
            {
                var M = await Materializer(reader, token);
                batchOfItems.Add(M);
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in batchOfItems)
        {
            yield return item;
        }

        scope.Complete(); //Asynch option not available
        //No need to have explicit rollback call, instead it's standard for that to happen upon disposal if not completed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to creating the `IAsyncEnumerable` by using a C# [iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators) could be to use the third-party library [AsyncEnumerator](https://github.com/Dasync/AsyncEnumerable) ([package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncEnumerator/)).

This library was the main resource for creating asynchronous enumerables before the advent of C# 8, and it may still be useful because AFAIK it doesn't suffer by the limitations of the native `yield`. You are allowed to have `try`, `catch` and `finally` blocks in the body of the lambda passed to the `AsyncEnumerable` constructor, and invoke the `yield.ReturnAsync` method from any of these blocks.

Usage example:

```
using Dasync.Collections;

//...

public IAsyncEnumerable<Item> Select()
{
    return new AsyncEnumerable<Item>(async yield => // This yield is a normal argument
    {
        await using var transaction = await con.BeginTransactionAsync(token);
        try
        {
            var batchOfItems = new List<Item>();
            await using (var reader = await com.ExecuteReaderAsync(SQL, token))
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync(token))
                {
                    var M = await Materializer(reader, token);
                    batchOfItems.Add(M);
                }
            }
            foreach (var item in batchOfItems)
            {
                await yield.ReturnAsync(item); // Instead of yield return item;
            }
            await transaction.CommitAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await transaction.RollbackAsync();
        }
    });
}
```

The `yield` in the above example is not the C# [yield contextual keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield), but just an argument with the same name. You could give it another name if you want.

Comment: This is a valid and good idea, thanks! It's not relevant for me, because I tend to heavily favour base classes, and eschew packages.

Comment: @Todd me too! But what would you do if you wanted to catch the exception inside the `Select` method in order to log it?

Comment: Very true. That's not a requirement of this question, but it certainly provides broader scope.